# test javascript string for complete URL to PDF

Tags: javascript, string, url, pdf

I have a form where I would like the user to input a complete URL that leads directly to a PDF (not a page that contains a pdf).

Currently I am testing (and adding if necessary) for http/https link this:

```
var str = textfield.value;

//test for http/https and add it if not there
var httpsInc = str.indexOf('https://') !== -1;
var httpInc = str.indexOf('http://') !== -1;
if ((httpsInc == false) & (httpInc == false)) {
    textfield.value = "http://" + str;
    var str = textfield.value;
}
```

and then testing that it is a valid URL (based on another post on here):

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?'+ // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|'+ // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))'+ // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*'+ // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?'+ // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$','i'); // fragment locator

if(!pattern.test(str)) {
    alert("Please enter a valid URL.");
    testresults=1;
} else {
    testresults=0;
}
return (testresults);
```

I was then going to add in the test for .pdf *[something like str.indexOf('.pdf') !== -1]* but I figured there must be a better way to do this. The RegExp above could likely do all of this testing for me I assume (test that .pdf is at the end etc), but I am unsure how to modify it. Is it better to modify it or just check that the last 4 characters of my string are ".pdf"?

Comment: I think the only way is to check that the last 4 characters are ".pdf", since the extension is the only real way to detect. So change the end of your regex to be `\.pdf$`

Comment: Be aware that URLs don’t necessarily have to correspond to file names – nothing stops me from serving an HTML document under `example.com/foo.pdf` The only half-decent way to check for actual PDF content would be to make a (HEAD) request for the URL and check the Content-Type header.

Comment: @CBroe Good point. I was only thinking of validating a string as a URL, not that it's an actual PDF file type. At the same time, there are several Content-Type headers you can use for serving files, depending on what you want to happen, so I wouldn't even say that's 100% reliable

Comment: Interesting. I was really more concerned with the URL going to a ".pdf" but perhaps checking that the document type is a "pdf" is more efficient anyway. Since really I want them to link to a pdf, the actual format of the URL is kind of irrelevant I suppose.